# Error while running gdal:polygonize as a background task

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-3, polygonize, tasks

I am trying to run gdal:polygonize as a background task, but I am getting QGIS crashing and giving me this error:

`QGIS died on signal 11ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No thread selected
No stack.
gdb returned 256
Aborted (core dumped)`

How can I go around debugging this?

this is the code for my plugin's module:

```
def polygonise(inputPath, outputPath, style=None):


    task = processingTask(inputPath, outputPath, style) 
    QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)



class processingTask(QgsTask):

    def __init__(self, inputPath, outputPath, style=None):
        QgsTask.__init__(self, "Publish layers")
        self.inputPath = inputPath
        self.outputPath = outputPath
        self.style = style
        self.exception = None
        self.errortrace = None

    def canCancel(self):
        return False

    def run(self):
        try:
            print("start processing")
            processing.run('gdal:polygonize', {'INPUT':self.inputPath,'BAND':1,'FIELD':'DN','EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS':False,'OUTPUT':self.outputPath})
            print("stop processing2")

            layer = QgsVectorLayer(self.outputPath, "{}_vectorised".format(self.inputPath.name()), "ogr")
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

            if not layer.isValid():
                print("Layer failed to load!")

            if not (self.style == None):
                categorizedStyling(layer, 'DN', self.style)
            return layer

        except Exception as e:            
            self.exception = e
            self.errortrace = traceback.format_exc()
        return False

    def finished(self, ok):
        if ok:
            print("Task is finished")
        else:
            print("Task has errors")
```

I have tried both methods (**Extending QgsTask** and **Task from a processing algorithm**) listed in the [QGSTask documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html) and both resulted in the same outcome.

`$ qgis --version`

`QGIS 3.4.14-Madeira 'Madeira' (exported)`

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask.html . That should do all this for you already.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I have tried it (as I mentioned in the question "Task from a processing algorithm") and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html has a huge red warning that says

> Any background task (regardless of how it is created) must NEVER use
> any QObject that lives on the main thread, such as accessing
> QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject or perform any GUI based operations like
> creating new widgets or interacting with existing widgets. (...)

Your code uses those. If you rework it, it will probably work without crashes.

Always read around the things you copy and paste, often there is valuable information there.